# Java - I have a abstract base class and I want to set few properties of base class from sub class

Tags: java, oop

Java - I have a abstract base class and I want to set few properties of base class from sub class. What is the best way to do it ?  Make the properties protected ?  Create setters in the base class ?

```
public abstract class A {
protected String tag;
protected String apiUrl;
    // Setter
    public void setApiUri(String url) {
        this.apiUrl = url;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    tag = "Class B";
    apiUrl = "Class B Prefs";
}

public class C extends A {
    tag = "Class C";
    apiUrl = "Class C Prefs";
}
```

Please let me know what is the best approach / any better way of doing it.

Comment: Create get/set in base class itself. Call them from Subclass when needed. Abstract class contain implemented methods.. For example public class C extends A {
    A(){ setTag("Class C");}.  
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want maximum encapsulation, make the base class fields private and provide protected accessors. This is usually the best practice.

If you're not too bothered about maximum encapsulation, you can make the fields protected, but it couples the classes together even more tightly than inheritance does (er) inherently.

In general, your best bet is the first option above. The JVM's JIT can optimize out the calls, and it helps keep the clases *somewhat* loosely-coupled.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation but usually you would like to preserve the state of the base class from the derived and give it full control of how it instantiates its own members. The best way to accomplish this is by specifying a constructor for the base class that inputs and initializes its members and call it from withing the concrete class. Here is an example:

```
abstract class Base{
    String s;
    int i;

    public Base(String s, int i){
        this.s = s; // Only base knows best how the initialization should be done
        this.i = i;
    }
}

class Concrete extends Base{

    // the role of the inheritor is to pass on the building blocks of its Base to Bases
    //constructor
    public Concrete(String s, int i) {
        super(s, i);
    }

}
```